# grails domain class compiled output file keep changing without modification

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class

I run "grails clean" first and then "grails war" to get the fresh distribution of the project. And the compiled output class(eg: Book.class) is keep changing after the above operations even without making any code modifications.
  It is strange or normal? Anyone can help me?

Yang.

Comment: There are a number of things that might cause that.  Without knowing more about the project it is difficult to say for sure.  One common thing that causes this if the package name in the class does not match the directory structure that the source is defined in.  That will cause the compiler to always think the class is out of date.

Comment: It seems like the groovy compiler is not deterministic when processing AST.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0EFn.png.  The location of @TraitBridge is changing.

Comment: Can you check if every time you call to `new Book()` is adding a Book.class?

Comment: I have posted an issue to grails https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/10868, and is closed as won't fix. As Jeff Scott Brown said, "The compiler doesn't make promises about things like order of methods in the bytecode, order of entries in the constant pool etc ". I doubt it's something related to groovy compiler and AST transformation at compile-time.