# Groovy injecting a trait at compile-time results in indeterministic byte code?

Tags: groovy

I have observed that the domain class compile output file(.class file) keep changing without modification to the source file(.groovy) in grails.
see:https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/10868 .
And [grails domain class compiled output file keep changing without modification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46091270/grails-domain-class-compiled-output-file-keep-changing-without-modification?noredirect=1#comment81818422_46091270) .
I doubt it's something related to groovy AST injecting. 
I have tested normal groovy class(without any AST), the compiled byte code is identical every time. Anyone can explain this symptom？

Comment: Here[https://www.dropbox.com/s/4l3lsmhuql8he9g/trait-compile.zip?dl=0] is a sample project can reproduce this symptom. Run "gradle clean compileGroovy" will output a different class every time. Any idea? It's any mechanism related to trait and the compiler?